# Get param and converto to string in Magento 2

Tags: php, magento2

I want to get the value from URL parameter `store`:
`http://localhost/magento_04/?store=angielski2`

I tried to do this by `$_GET['store']`, but it doesn't work.

I tried also by using:
`$language = $this->getRequest()->getParam('store');`

Comment: Welcome on SO ! Can you please explain "but it doesn't work" ? :)

Comment: Nothing is displayed.

Comment: Can you try something like ```var_dump($_GET);```?

Comment: I have edited your post to remove the greeting, since those aren't needed here.   I also changes some technical wording.  Instead of "rewrite" it appears you mean "get" and instead of "variable", you appear to be talking about parameters from the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Andre! :) I just solved the problem. I spent 4 hours on this issue but the solution was very simple:
    `

```
$site_name = "";
$language = $this->getRequest()->getParam('___store');
echo gettype($language);
echo $language;
if ($language== "sweden")
{
    echo "costam";
    $site_name = "costam";
} else{
    $site_name = "somethingelse";

}
echo $site_name;

?>
`
```